# Sound changes of "wild" and "wilderness"

Tags: etymology, nouns, vowels

I'm having a heated a discussion with a friend and we cannot really get on the same level.

In the original pronunciation of the word *wild*, the "i" was the short sound that we have in the word *wilderness* today. How has the vowel sound in *wild* changed up to its present pronunciation and why hasn't the "i" in *wilderness* changed in the same way?

Comment: See *child, children* for a milder example,

Answer (score 13):

This is an alternation referred to as [Trisyllabic laxing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trisyllabic_laxing) in English phonology literature. Consult the Wikipedia page for further examples. The process predates the Great Vowel Shift, which concerned only long vowels. So vowels which were made lax and short by trisyllabic laxing were effectively "shielded" from sound change.