# Is there a rule that describes vowel pronunciation changes in conjugated words?

Tags: pronunciation, vowels

I've noticed that sometimes when a word (generally a noun or adjective) gains or loses syllables, the pronunciation of the vowels will change. For example,

- horizon vs horizontal
- sociopath vs sociopathy
- photograph vs photographer

What I want to know is if there is a general rule that describes why this occurs. I also know that not every time the syllable count is changed the pronunciation changes. For instance, the addition of the suffix *-ly* seems to maintain the rest of the pronunciation despite adding a syllable. I found [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52988/is-there-a-rule-for-the-pronunciation-of-words-with-the-suffix-ative), talking about pronunciation change in words that end in -ative, which seems to be related but more focused.

I suspect it's something to do with syllable stress, but it's difficult for me to research this without a search engine simply giving me the Great Vowel Shift or a 5th grade lesson on syllables. Of course I don't expect there to be a perfectly descriptive rule with no exceptions, but it seems to be common enough to warrant some kind of explanation.

**Edit: It appears that trisyllabic laxing is what I was looking for. Questions that mention it such as [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92262/sound-changes-of-wild-and-wilderness/92265#92265) answer my question perfectly. Thank you @tchrist**

Comment: It's not so much the syllable count as it is the stress accent shifting. Most English vowels only occur when they're stressed; if the stress in the word shifts, the original vowel is apt to become unstressed, which changes its pronunciation (usually to schwa, or something like it), while previously unstressed vowels get a more precise pronunciation. This is English Phonology, Vowel Reduction subclass.

Comment: [This is why](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=trisyllabic+laxing).